# How to assign an array when calling asynchronous functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-translate

I'm using AngularJS and [Angular Translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/). I have an array of objects that have 'key' property - a string that should be translated.

This is my array of objects:

```
var objects = [{
        id: 1,
        key: 'Jacket'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        key: 'Trousers'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        key: 'Hat'
    }];
```

These are my translations:

```
var translationsEN = { 
    Jacket: 'This is Jacket in English',
    Trousers: 'This is Trousers in English',
    Hat: 'This is Hat in English'
}
```

When some particular events occur I need an array of the objects but with the translations, not with the keys. That's why I have a function that does the following:

```
var translatedObjects = [];

for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    $translate(objects[i].key).then(function (translation) {
        translatedObjects[i] = translation;
    });
}
```

After the function execution the result stored in the translatedObjects array is:

```
[null,null,null,"This is Hat in English"]
```

I guess that this is happening because I'm actually executing an asynchronous call to the $translate service and translatedObject[i] is not actually pointing to the right object, because 'i' is not defined in the current context.

So, how can I execute an asynchronous function call and assign my array appropriately as shown in the example above?

Comment: for loop wont wait for the unsync operation to get complete.

Comment: Yes, and what can I do to achieve the result that I expected?

Comment: with recursive call to a function you can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the for loop will have completed and the value of `i` will be `3` when the callback fires. The three callbacks will then overwrite the value at the same index three times.

You can encapsulate your variable in a new scope:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    $translate(objects[i].key).then((function(x) { 
        return function (translation) {
           translatedObjects[x] = translation;
        };
    })(i));
}
```

What happens above is you create an anonymous function that accepts a parameter, `x`, and returns a callback function. So when you call that function passing `i=0`, it will return a callback function which has access to `x=0` from the scope in which it was created. At the next iteration, the anonymous function will be called again, and return a new callback function, where `x` is 1, etc.

If you know that the callbacks will be called sychronously, and assigning to an array is all you want to do, then ngLover's answer is probably more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `push` method of array to insert data . don't need to pass `i` since it will be inserted in same sequence.

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    $translate(objects[i].key).then(function (translation) {
        $scope.translatedObjects.push(translation);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the order of translated strings is guaranteed here? What if the first call to `$translate()` takes more time than the second?

Comment: @ShanShan ya shaan if $translate does and async task then david method of using closures is correct one.

Comment: I prefer my `Promise.all` solution though, cleaner and less nesting but OP made his choice :D

Answer (score 0):

You're already using promises so you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    promises.push($translate(objects[i].key));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function (translatedObjects) {
    // use your array here
});
```